# Constrain ASP.NET MVC Route Parameter Value (Exactly 1 Letter A-Za-z)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

How can I constrain an MVC route parameter to be only A-Za-z and exactly 1 letter? (Looking for the validation Regex). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z]$
```